# Any difference between a $ wrap function and getElementById?

Tags: javascript, css

I mean a wrap function like this:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

but in some code like this:

```
oDiv1 = $("postInfoDiv");
oDiv2 = document.getElementById("postInfoDiv");
alert(oDiv1 == oDiv2);                     // return false
alert(oDiv1.style);                            // error
alert(oDiv2.style);                            // correct
alert(document.getElementById("postInfoDiv").style); // correct
```

I got strange results as the comments imply.
I thought the first alert should return the true since they are the same dom object.
I thought the second alert should alert something like "object" or "CSS StyleDeclaration" but not "defined".

So what are the problems? Have you ever met this kind of problems?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `alert(oDiv1.style)` instead of `alert(oDiv.style)`?

Comment: The second one is maybe just because you never declare an "oDiv", you declare an "oDiv1" and "oDiv2" but never an "oDiv".

Comment: `alert(oDiv1 == oDiv2);` is returning `true` for me as it should.

Comment: @KennyTM I'm sorry. I wrote it wrong, it should be `alert(oDiv1.style)`.

Comment: What browser are you having issues with this? Seems to be working fine for me when I run this in IE8. Do you have another framework on the page?

Comment: I am using FF 3.6.8, IE 8, Opera 10.61.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$` function is probably being overridden, potentially by a framework.

You should try doing `alert( oDiv1.nodeType )` to see if it's a DOM element. `alert( oDiv1.length )` to see if it's an empty array because you may be using jQuery on the same page which overrides your `$` function.

`oDiv1` may be an array-like object containing that item if jQuery is included. `oDiv2` is an actual DOM reference. You probably need to compare `oDiv1[0]` to `oDiv1`, in which you reference the first element in the array which points to the **actual** dom element to make a fair comparison.

```
function $(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
$('content') == document.getElementById('content')
true
```

The custom `$` function will work perfectly but if you're using a framework function it will return that array-like object instead of the DOM element.

You can also rename your function to something like `function getID` which would be unique and not conflict with framework `$`s.

Comment: Did you look at his $ function in the question? No array there.

Comment: Why would `oDiv1`  be an array?

Comment: He's most likely accidentally using another `$` function instead of the one he defined. Maybe he has Prototype/jQuery on the same page. Otherwise it wouldn't equate to false.

Comment: @meder: Yes, I have jQuery on the same page. How did you know it? But I have searched the jQuery source code but could not find  a function name $(),though I am sure jQuery has one.

Comment: jQuery IS defined as `window.$`. You can use `jQuery.noConflict` to make jQuery not use `$` but it would break your code. If you try this in a page without jQuery, it'll work perfectly. Soo, I suggest renaming your function or just not using your custom `$` because you're already using jQuery. There is no difference between your function and just using gEBI.

Comment: @jcyang: By default `$ == jQuery`.

Comment: @meder: I changed the '$', and it works. It is the conflict between this $ function and jQuery that produce these strange results. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My main concern with this is that it will confuse the heck out of someone the first time they read your code, especially if they are used to coding with a JavaScript framework such as jQuery.

For this reason alone I recommend you do not use this particular syntax for your wrap function.

Comment: Asking the OP not to use a convenient shorthand because it's common in other libraries doesn't seem like a reasonable answer to his question.  Using that logic jQuery shouldn't use $ because Prototype does, or vice versa.  You can't assume a JS Project uses a specific library because of a $() function.

Comment: The accepted answer essentially says the same thing I am - to rename his function because it is conflicting with jQuery.

Comment: i was going to say the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

BTW note that even when jQuery is not loaded, Firebug provides its own $ function, which may participate to confusion.

Comment: Oh, I debuged this page with Firebug too.